# Why Can You Not Duplicate A List And Lose The 1st Index Of the List?

Tags: python, list

I was trying to make a list (for recursive purposes) that would not contain that list's [1] index. However, when I tried doing this, by instantiating an empty list and then appending the rest of the list to it, the output shows that the list is empty. I was wondering if there was a specific reason or concept for why it was not creating the special list that I wanted.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(list().append(0).append(a[1:]))
```

The output should be [1,3,4,5] but is instead "None".

Sure, I could make a function and piece it all together but that doesn't feel nearly as intuitive or elegant.

Comment: Can you explain a little better? You start with list [1,2,3,4,5] and what is your desired output?

Comment: It doesn't work because `append` returns None.

Comment: Do you mean `print([a[0]] + a[2:])` (outputs `[1, 3, 4, 5]`)?

Comment: Yes, thats my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ass @Daniel Roseman said, append function returns None.

If I understand what you want to achieve, create a little function and just do:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

def addAndReturn(ls, elem):
  ls.append(elem)
  return ls

print(addAndReturn(addAndReturn(list(), 0), a[1:]))
```

result:

> [0, [2, 3, 4, 5]]

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation.  `append` is a `list` class method that alters the object.  It has no return value; `None` is the default.  Your expression reduces to

```
print(None.append([2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Which, in turn, has a return value of `None`.
You can make your new list simply with

```
new_list = a[1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

`append` appends to a list and returns `None`. You should save this new list to a variable and then print it. E.g.

```
newlist = list() # or just[]
newlist.append(0)
newlist.extend(a[1:]) # OP had append, but you probably meant "extend"
print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `append` method adds an element to its object but returns `None`. What you want is the list addition:

```
print(list() + [0] + [a[1:]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a new list, and extend it from there:

```
b = [0]
b.extend(a[1:])
```